# Why does Cucumber automatically load .rb files outside of features/support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm reading **The Cucumber Book** and it mentions that all files in the `features/support` directory are automatically required - with `env.rb` being required first.  I don't like the fact that we can't control the order in which files are required when we put them in `features/support`, so I created a `features/setup` directory to hold my .rb files. I then require them, in the order I need, in the `env.rb` file.  My `features/support` folder only contains `env.rb`.

I'm seeing files get required twice.  It looks like cucumber is requiring any `.rb` file, regardless of which folder it is in.  Why is this happening?  I've been running cucumber with

```
bundle exec cucumber -r features
```

I have a `config/cucumber.yml` with

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] ||      'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #   {rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags    ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

but I don't think it's causing the problem.  Has something changed in cucumber since **The Cucumber Book** was written that makes cucumber load all `.rb` files under `features`?  Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything within the features/ folder will be loaded by cucumber. I can't speak to what is written in the book, but as per one of the cucumber book's authors:

> If you want explicit loading and not automatic loading, just put your
>   files outside the features folder.

[Source](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/cukes/oDxkh_DQA4g/Ggix_e3PGDkJ)

I would also say that, if you don't need to do the loading yourself, you should probably just let it work the way it was intended. At the very least, people already experienced with cucumber will have a better idea of how your project works.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: That's really annoying. I can't compartmentalize my test code the way I want. Thanks for the info though